# Display brightness inversed on Toshiba Satellite L555

Tags: xorg, 17.10, brightness, amd-graphics, backlight

I installed Ubuntu Mate 17.10 on my Toshiba L555 and the control of the brightness now works inversed, very annoying when enabling the dim function in the power manager as the display goes brighter instead of dimmer.
Before I was running Ubuntu 16.4 LTS and don't remember having this issue.
Anyone has an idea?

steven@STEVEN-TOSHIBA:~$ ls /sys/class/backlight/

acpi_video0  radeon_bl0

Content of /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-radeon.conf:

Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "Radeon"
        MatchDriver "radeon"
        Driver "radeon"
EndSection